# NGINX Load balancing or stronger hardware? Please explain

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a web application and expect it to be getting many concurrent users. I have seen engineers use load balancing to achieve optimal efficiency but I still don't see how buying more servers is better than just upgrading the current hardware to say, a 64 core processor and an intel 750 ssd. NGINX should already utilize these cores and create separate processes for these cores and balance the load between the cores already no?

Really what I am getting at, is the cost. Why purchase another motherboard, another chassis, psu, etc. when you can just upgrade the current hardware?

Comment: `when you can just upgrade the current hardware?` Other factors aside you can do that to a point - and then it's cheaper to have multiple machines instead of one beast.

Comment: Well, having beast hardware to begin with is really the way to go. That way, if you do need to get another server, it's reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Redundancy, resiliency, scalability and flexibility are factors here.

Many environments *can* and *do* scale beyond a single server in the web-tier. It also makes sense to understand what the realistic bottleneck of the environment is: CPU? RAM? Network?

Comment: Sure the server can fail at any moment, but what are the odds of that? When first deploying my application, you are saying not to purchase super great hardware, but instead to scale as needed? Sure it makes sense, but why be reactive rather than proactive?

Comment: I said nothing about using subpar hardware. I suggested that flexibility is key. What if you need to run an important OS update or perform hardware maintenance? Multiple servers in your load balancing pool are extremely handy for that.